# How to automate subtotals in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Good afternoon,

I have attached an example of what i am trying to figure out. But i have looked an cannot find something that can help.

I want a formula that will automate the subtotals and it will do the following:

1. if there is a "+" on column A it will sum all above numbers on column C that based on "." but it will stop to the last "*" on column A

for example if i am in cell C23 it should add everything up to cell C15 (as you will see i have put a 100 at cell C14 but this should not be added in the formula.)

I am trying to figure out a formula that i would drug down and it would perform the above, similarly if i drug it will add the same in cell C34.

The end results should be the same as i have done manually.

Hopefully the above makes sense. Thank you very much for any help, really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far and explain the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Good afternoon, I dont really know a formula maybe something with the sumifs, but i dont know how to "ask" the formula to stop summing up to the last "*".

Comment: Sorry - pressed enter quickly.  The problem is that I cant think of a way to do the calculation i described above. thank you

Answer (score 1):

With a helper column (you can hide it).
In column D:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A3,"~*")
```

and copy down. It counts the number of `*` so far.
In column C in rows with `+` (e.g. in C12):

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$1:$C11,($A$1:$A11=".")*($D$1:$D11=D12))
```

[image: Sum between * and +]

Comment: Thank you, thats a simple and great way to make it work. I had it a lot more complicated in my mind than this.

Comment: @VasileiosGeorgakopoulos Please consider marking the Accept as answer flag if this resolves your question.